# Using google home app cannot control box connect wifi

Tags: wifi

I have a GTV12 version set-top box, but the Google Home networking function in the startup wizard has been failing. The box is already connected to the network and can ping Google, but the phone still shows that it is connected. After a period of time, it prompts that the device cannot be found

Attempting to replace the wifi of MTK, the function is normal